# Putting info on the right side of a tab in a vertical format

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Angular-ui for bootstrap (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and for the tabs, if I want to use the vertical version of it, the text always appears on the bottom. How do I make the text appear on the right side of the tabs?

Code... (taken straight from the website)

```
<tabset vertical="true" type="pills">
    <tab heading="Vertical 1">Vertical content 1</tab>
    <tab heading="Vertical 2">Vertical content 2</tab>
</tabset>
```

Comment: Post the current code and output.

Comment: I guess I did... the code is copied straight from the link I posted though.

Comment: Maybe something custom in CSS?

Comment: Found this: http://plnkr.co/edit/UBBq7V8mdyqllBHdwegY?p=preview but it's not quite what I want (I'd like pills)

Comment: anyone? i feel like it's a simple problem but i don't have much knowledge in html...